# How do I put the items I picked in listview to my database?

Tags: vb.net

[See pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQhOj.jpg) 
Just new to vb.net. Anyway, I don't know how I will put the value of product and price I picked in the database since it's in the list view. I tried 
Dim txtValue as String
txtValue = ListView1.FocusedItem.SubItems(0).text. To get the values of the columns.
In the picture I provided, If I the put the customername and I pick her order in the listview1 it will save in my database. And it will show it my listview2. Just disregard the address.
UPDATE I think this code works but there's still error message showing up.[Error message see pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmJoN.png)

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("server=.\SQL;database=try;Trusted_Connection=TRUE")
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim cmd2 As SqlCommand
    Dim rdr As SqlDataReader

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        con.Open()
        con.Close()
        list()

        list2()
    End Sub
    Sub list()
        con.Open()


        cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ProductTable", con)
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        ListView1.Items.Clear()
        If rdr.HasRows Then
            Do While rdr.Read()
                Dim arr As String() = New String(2) {}
                Dim itm As ListViewItem

                arr(0) = rdr("productID")
                arr(1) = rdr("product")
                arr(2) = rdr("price")

                itm = New ListViewItem(arr)
                ListView1.Items.Add(itm)


            Loop

        End If

        con.Close()
    End Sub


    Private Sub btnsave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnsave.Click

        modifyrecord("Insert into ProductOrder([name],[product],[price]) values ('" & txtname.Text & "','" & ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text & "'," & ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text & "")



    End Sub
    Private Sub listView1_MouseClick_1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)

    End Sub

    Sub list2()
        con.Open()


        cmd2 = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ProductOrder", con)
        rdr = cmd2.ExecuteReader
        ListView2.Items.Clear()
        If rdr.HasRows Then
            Do While rdr.Read()
                Dim arr As String() = New String(3) {}
                Dim itm As ListViewItem

                arr(0) = rdr("id")
                arr(1) = rdr("name")
                arr(2) = rdr("product")
                arr(3) = rdr("price")

                itm = New ListViewItem(arr)
                ListView2.Items.Add(itm)


            Loop

        End If

        con.Close()
    End Sub
    Sub modifyrecord(ByVal sql)

        If txtname.Text = "" Or ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text = "" Or IsNumeric(ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text) = False Then


        Else
            con.Open()
            cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
            list()

        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It would be much much much easier with a DataGridView since thats what they are made for.  There is not much there for inserting to help with. Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: First of all, do you know how to insert data into a database?

Comment: yes. I just don't know how to do it with listview.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
txtValue = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text
txtValue1 = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text
```

To get the Product and price from the list view
I assume you have the MultiSelect set to false.

Comment: I think it works but there's an error message. See the pic above.

Comment: What is the error? I looked at the picture but it did not say what the error was. I would be surprised if the data type of price was a string. Can you verify that?

Comment: the data type of price was int, I don't know why it says "Incorrect syntax near '100'."

Comment: You would not have to worry about single quotes around an integer. The quotes are for strings. You wouldn't have these problems if you used parameters in your SQL string. The use Command.Parameters.Add("parameterName", SQLDataType).Value = yourValue. Turn on Option Strict and you will be forced to do conversions. Declare your txtValue1 variable As Integer. You have moved on to different questions. Please post a new question and marked this as answered. Your original question about getting values from a list view has been answered, Right. Thank you.